# Rails 3 'request_via_redirect' trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-api

I have a trouble with [request_via_redirect](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Integration/RequestHelpers/request_via_redirect)

How i use this method:

```
  def synchronize
    request_via_redirect(:post, synchronize_companies_path, params)
  end
```

And get an error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `request_via_redirect' for #<Companies::ApiController:0x00000006739a00>):
```

Anybody can explain what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are using a rspec integration method. 
`request_via_redirect`, `post_via_redirect` and other methods like that are made to work with testing integration environment. Those functions only work inside a test/spec kind of file.

Try changing your code to the following:

```
def synchronize
    require "uri"
    require "net/http"
    Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse(synchronize_companies_path), params)
end
```

I am pretty sure that there's a better way of doing what you want to do. Some more information about your intentions should help.